# Why the index of a certain chapter is put on 2 chapters later?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm using a template, not created by me, for the thesis.
I use the index for each chapter. (minitoc)
Why the index of a certain chapter is put on 2 chapters later? i.e. the index of chapter 1 is on chapter 3. 
In this [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/try.rar) there are the code and the pdf.

Comment: could you make a copy of your code, strip the copy down to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that reproduces the error, and post it in your question? Quite often, the process of creating a MWE will help you fix the issue :)

Comment: I'm create my MWE and I link it in my document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between `minitoc` and the KOMA option `listof=totoc`; load the package [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) and remove that option when declaring the class, i.e., use

```
\documentclass[
  b5paper,
  10pt,
  twoside,
  parskip=half,
  numbers=noenddot,
  bibliography=totocnumbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

Nt the way, you are using packages which are not fully compatible with KOMA classes; keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: yeah!!!!!!!!!!!! it works!!!! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @cesarino87 You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that you consider best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).